# Tapping into thermistor output

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, analog, temperature, thermistor

Background: automotive application, '79 oldtimer with a Cylinder Head Temperature (CHT) sensor (a 2-wire NTC thermistor) that is fed into an analogue electronic control unit (ECU). The sensor output is only visible to the ECU and used for fuel injection management. Also, I don't have visibility of the ECU circuit that conditions the thermistor signal (the ECU has 3 proprietary hybrid ICs with no datasheet available).

Some more notes:

- One end of the thermistor is grounded, the other feeds into the ECU.
- I've got +12 V and enough current available for additional circuitry, though.

I would like to monitor and display the engine temperature with a vintage analogue gauge. The obvious option is to install a second CHT sensor. Yet mounting an additional sensor on the engine case is non-trivial, and given that there is already a sensor, why not reuse its output?

I'm looking for a circuit that would allow me to tap into or split the thermistor output so that I can read the resulting additional output with the gauge. I would worry about matching the sensor output to the gauge later, but is this something that could be achieved without upsetting the ECU temperature reading?

**Update**: just for the background's sake, while the ECU schematics are not available, there is  circuit diagram of the next generation of that particular ECU online: [image: a circuit diagram of the next generation of that particular ECU]

In that picture, I've marked the engine temperature sensing thermistor in red. The schematics, without being exact are probably close enough to get an idea of the circuitry behind the sensor that I'd like to tap into.

The BS10, BS20 and BS30 are the more modern DIP versions of the proprietary hybrid ICs in my ECU, while the rest of ICs are LM2902 quad op-amps.

Comment: It could be achieved but it may take some fiddling around with things and without a schematic of what feeds the thermistor "fiddling around" is non-definable as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the original answer with some more background about an approximation of what could be feeding the thermistor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a thermistor is biased with a low constant current supply and the resulting voltage across it is measured to determine the temperature. If you select an op amp or instrumentation amp with sufficiently high input impedance (e.g. > 1 megohm) you can use this to measure the voltage across the thermistor without disturbing the incumbent ECU electronics. Due to the high input impedance, you should consider incorporating a low pass filter to reduce noise pick up.

The new op amp circuit can then drive an analog voltmeter that can be calibrated with a temperature scale. You can determine the op amp gain, offset, and scaling factor empirically if you do not have access to the NTC specs and knowledge of its bias current.

Comment: It was a tough call, as both you and Olin Lathrop had good answers. I'm picking yours as you posted it first, and given that you've got less rep points than him, I'm hoping to contribute to bring these up :)

Answer (score 1):

Picking off the analog reading from the thermistor is probably not too hard.

There is a good chance that one side is connected to ground.  In that case, the voltage on the other gives you a measure of temperature directly.  If the thermistor is floating or one side connected to power, then a instrumentation amp taking the differential signal will give you a single-ended ground-referenced analog signal that is somehow related to temperature.

Filter and clip the lines separately to prevent voltage spikes from causing trouble.  As long as your diff amp presents high impedance, the existing circuit won't see anything different.

Going from that to a temperature display is more complicated.  Your spec is to drive a analog gauge.  OK, that's your preference.  However, then you get into a implementation detail and say no A/D is to be used.  That doesn't belong in a spec.  The job of a spec is to explain *what* you want done, not *how* you want it done.  With proper specs, if they are met you get what you want.  How that is achieved shouldn't matter to you.

Your problem now comes down to having a voltage that is somehow a function of temperature on one side, and a gauge that displays temperature as some other function of voltage or current.  You're not going to find a lot of temperature gauges of the size and temperature range you want, and you're very very unlikely to find one that has even close to the inverse response of the thermistor output.

The solution is to read the thermistor signal (after filtering and diff amp) digitally, perform the non-linear conversion to the analog gauge input, then use that to drive the gauge.  Driving the gauge can be done from a PWM output of the same microcontroller that reads the thermistor signal.  Analog movements inherently low pass filter and display the average, so feeding them raw PWM pulses is fine.  Even just a few 10s of Hz is good enough, so you can have lots more PWM duty cycle resolution than the gauge can show.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Based on your comments, I've updated the original question to clarify some of the points. I can confirm from the vehicle schematics and from measuring it myself that the thermistor is grounded in one end. The other is fed into the ECU, and I can only make an educated guess (see updated question) of what's behind it. In terms of using an ADC, that's fine, apologies if I wasn't clear about that. I simply meant that the _analog gauge_ that I've got has no digital circuitry. I'm fine with adding digital circuitry between the sensor and the gauge as you are describing.

Comment: Btw, thanks also for addressing the matching from sensor output to the gauge. I'll address that in a separate question to keep this one on topic.

Comment: The thermistor may not be continuously driven.  Driving it may interfere with the car's measurement.  The OP will need to tap off the analog signal and look at it to figure out what's going on.  It might be necessary to try to sync to when the car is trying to read temp.